# Apple HealthKit : How to set the Date of Birth in the Simulator

Tags: healthkit

How can I set the birthdate in watchOS simulator. Seems to be write protected?

[image: Scrreenshot Apple Watch Simulator]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pair the Watch with a simulated iPhone and set the birthdate there. No way to do it directly via the watch.

You can do so under "manage run destinations" in Xcode. Pick a simulated iPhone and pair with a Watch. Start the iPhone Simulator, open the health app and set the data.

[image]